# observer div element size/dimensions using useRef and window resize event (React Hook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, window-resize, use-ref

I am trying to constantly observe/detect a div element size using React Hook JS. I have used different ways but every time I see a common issue where decreasing window size doesn't change the  `ref.current.offsetWidth` but increasing it, will change `ref.current.offsetWidth` value.

Here is my code:

```
function Chart({}) {
    const targetRef = useRef(null);
    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({width: 0, height: 0});

    const updateDimensions = debounce(() => {
        if(targetRef.current) {
            setDimensions({
                width: targetRef.current.offsetWidth,
                height: targetRef.current.offsetHeight
            });
        }
    }, 50);

    useEffect(() => {
        updateDimensions();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
        updateDimensions();
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={{minHeight: 250}} ref={targetRef}>
           <some svg component/>
        </div>

    );
}
```

**Note:** Re-rendering the entire app will update the dimensions, but I don't want to refresh the whole page to get the right size.

Comment: is [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-smztod) what you want?

Comment: this is almost what I am doing, but I still get the same problem in my App.

Comment: I have a hunch that the styling of the div means the rendered size doesn't change on a window resize - and hence the offsetWidth and offsetHeight do not change. As a test, if you add `height: "100vh", width: "100vw"` to your style prop, do you then see the dimensions change?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure the size of certain elements using refs (or using a raw element even), then I recommend this library:
https://github.com/ZeeCoder/use-resize-observer

If you want to measure the size of the window specifically, then probably best to use something like this: https://github.com/jaredLunde/react-hook/tree/master/packages/window-size#readme